# fastNlMeansDenoising returned NULL without setting an error

Tags: opencv

I am trying to process single channel uint16 image, using opencv fastNlMeansDenoising, I get "SystemError:  returned NULL without setting an error". Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am using opencv-python 3.4.3.18, python 3.6

```
template_windows_size = 9
search_window_size = 21
image = image.astype('uint16')
dst = np.zeros_like(image)
dst = dst.astype('uint16')
image_post_denoising = cv.fastNlMeansDenoising(image, regulating_filer_h, dst, template_windows_size, search_window_size, cv.NORM_L1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regulating_filer_h = np.array([120.0]) 
template_windows_size = 9
search_window_size = 21
image = image.astype('uint16')
image_denoised = cv.fastNlMeansDenoising(src=image, h=regulating_filer_h, templateWindowSize=template_windows_size, searchWindowSize=search_window_size, normType=cv.NORM_L1)
```